# Orange HTC Hero Unlock problems

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-hero

Orange being the unhelpful company that it is, can't unlock phones in the shop.  This was unfortunate as I was going overseas, but no matter, I called the helpline, and then was told it'll take three weeks - to get the IMEI sent to HTC, and get the unlock code back.

I had no choice so I waited, and after three weeks I got the code.  Of course, it didn't work.  I checked, and they've used the wrong IMEI number.  This means another 3 weeks, at least, and I'm meanwhile stuck roaming with my smartphone, which is NOT cheap, plus I can't terminate my contract with them until it's unlocked.

Sooo...while I wait out the time again in the hope they don't screw it up *again*, I wondered if it's possible to either unlock it by other methods, or to root it and whether that would negate the need for unlocking?

HTC Hero originally running 1.5, now 2.1 update 1, with Orange UK.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the online unlocking websites.

If you're paranoid, see if your bank still offers limited-use credit cards with a very small limit for online purchases, or use a pre-paid card.